# Getting a list of all classloaders in a JVM

Tags: java, weblogic

Is it possible to get a list of all class loaders in a JVM or at least all class loaders associated with web apps in a Java EE Server (WebLogic in my case).

Answer (score 8):

There are good overviews on the class loader hierarchy at:

[Archived version of http://e-docs.bea.com/wls/docs81/programming/classloading.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20090619193125/http://e-docs.bea.com/wls/docs81/programming/classloading.html)

http://weblogic.sys-con.com/node/42876

You can use

```
ClassLoader.getParent()
```

to walk through you current application's applications resolution tree, but you really can't look through the children app's class loaders.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1026905/21851535) with the following to get near to every classloader.

```java
Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet() //Get all active threads
.stream()
.map(thread -> thread.getContextClassLoader()) //Get the classloader of the thread (may be null)
.filter(Objects::nonNull) //Filter out every null object from the stream
.toList()
```