# How to get list of all loaded Classes by all JVM ClassLoaders, which is anotated by some anotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, classloader

I looked at this, but this is not helpful for me.
[Getting a list of all classloaders in a JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026630/getting-a-list-of-all-classloaders-in-a-jvm)

I am making my own injecting library and I want to use annotations to markup classes which will be instantiated at injector start. Is there a way to get list of all loaded Classes by all JVM ClassLoaders, which is anotated by some anotation?

Is it possible to do this with for example "org.reflections" dependency or similar?

Thanks for your help

Comment: As that link points out, you can't get all classloaders.  You can get all classes from a classloader, and then search them for your annotation.  I would be very surprised if there were a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Where is all classloaders references stored while runtime? There must be a way to get all of them at runtime. Or is possible to change constructor of java.lang.object with reflection at runtime and add my code to every java Object :D? Best time to start learning bytecode...

Comment: Why must there be a way to get all of them at runtime?

Comment: Everything can be achieved if desired, but it may not be an effective and good solution.

Comment: [`java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses%28%29) might help.

Comment: There is a contradiction in your requirements. You should first decide whether you really want *all loaded* classes only or rather all classes *available on the class path*. When your injection only works with already loaded classes, their loading must be triggered manually by the application which contradicts the goal of injecting them automatically.

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. I want to get all classes and instantiate classes annotated with @EagerSingleton as eager singletons. java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses looks like very useful for me thanks!